# Sum and bubble-sort student scores

Tags: performance, beginner, c, sorting, homework

I am a beginner in C language.

I studied all night and did my assignment.

But I wonder if there is a more efficient way.

The original structure is this.

```
typedef struct student {
    int id;
    int prob_1;
    int prob_2;
    int prob_3;
    int total_score;
    char grade;
}Student
```

I used typedef to change it to Student.

And I'll show you the contents of the function.

```
void cal_total_score(Student* s) {
    /*
    Problem (A):
    Implement the function "cal_total_score".
    - In each student, total_score must be the sum of prob_1, prob_2, and prob_3.
    - The codes outside the function must not be changed.
    */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
        s[i].total_score = s[i].prob_1 + s[i].prob_2 + s[i].prob_3;
    }
}

void student_bb_sort(Student* s) {
    /*
    Problem (B):
    Implement the function "student_bb_sort".
    - The student array "s" must be sorted according to total_score.
    - Bubble sort algorithm should be used for the sorting.
    - The codes outside the function must not be changed.
    */
    Student tmp;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUMSTUDENT - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (s[j].total_score > s[j + 1].total_score) {
                tmp = s[j];
                s[j] = s[j + 1];
                s[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there are any more wrong or dangerous phrases or efficient ways.

---

This is a given main function in advance, so read it if you need it.

> ```
> typedef struct student {
>     int id;
>     int prob_1;
>     int prob_2;
>     int prob_3;
>     int total_score;
>     char grade;
> }Student;
>
> void cal_total_score(Student* s);
> void student_bb_sort(Student* s);
>
> int main() {
>     Student s[NUMSTUDENT];
>     int i;
>
>     for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
>         s[i].id = i;
>         s[i].prob_1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
>         s[i].prob_2 = rand() % 30 + 1;
>         s[i].prob_3 = rand() % 40 + 1;
>         printf("Student %d\nP1: %d\tP2: %d\tP3: %d\n", s[i].id, s[i].prob_1, s[i].prob_2, s[i].prob_3);
>     }
>
>     for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
>         cal_total_score(&s[i]);
>         printf("Student %d\tScore: %d\n", s[i].id, s[i].total_score);
>     }
>
>     student_bb_sort(s);
>     printf("\nAfter Bubble Sort\n");
>
>     for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
>         if ((float)i < (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3) {
>             s[i].grade = 'C';
>         }
>         else if ((float)i < (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3 * 2 && (float)i >= (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3) {
>             s[i].grade = 'B';
>         }
>         else {
>             s[i].grade = 'A';
>         }
>         printf("Student %d\tScore: %d\tGrade: %c\n", s[i].id, s[i].total_score, s[i].grade);
>     }
> ```

Comment: Did you have a look at [C bubble sort@CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+%22bubble+sort%22)?

Answer (score 3):

**Advice 1**

```
typedef struct student {
    int id;
    int prob_1;
    int prob_2;
    int prob_3;
    int total_score;
    char grade;
}Student;
```

Since `prob_1`, `prob_2`, `prob_3` and `total_score` are supposed to be positive integers, I suggest you change their types to `unsigned int`. (Don't forget to include `<stdlib.h>`.) Also, I personally would change the type of `id` to `size_t`, too. Finally, you can `typedef` the `student` to `student` with the prefix `s` and not `S`. This buys you the possibility to declare the student data in both flavors:

```
struct student s1;
student s2;
```

**Advice 2**

Don't use magic numbers. You could write:

```
#define NUM_STUDENTS 3
#define MAX_PROBLEM_1_SCORE 30
#define MAX_PROBLEM_2_SCORE 30
#define MAX_PROBLEM_3_SCORE 40

#define MAX_SCORE (MAX_PROBLEM_1_SCORE + MAX_PROBLEM_2_SCORE + MAX_PROBLEM_3_SCORE)
```

**Advice 3**

A common pattern for accepting arrays via function arguments is to pass the pointer to the leftmost array component and the lenght of the array:

```
void cal_total_score(student* s, size_t length);
void student_bb_sort(student* s, size_t length);
```

**Advice 4**

Seed you random:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Or otherwise, you will produce exactly the same random numbers. (Don't forget to include `<time.h>` for `time(NULL)`.)

**Advice 5**

```
for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
    s[i].id = i;
    s[i].prob_1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
    s[i].prob_2 = rand() % 30 + 1;
    s[i].prob_3 = rand() % 40 + 1;
    printf("Student %d\nP1: %d\tP2: %d\tP3: %d\n", s[i].id, s[i].prob_1, s[i].prob_2, s[i].prob_3);
}

for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
    cal_total_score(&s[i]);
    printf("Student %d\tScore: %d\n", s[i].id, s[i].total_score);
}
```

Why not combine all the output into one `for` loop?

**Advice 6**

You could optimize your bubble sort to quit when a pass over the student array does not lead to swapping the students in the array. See below:

**Alternative implementation**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_STUDENTS 3
#define MAX_PROBLEM_1_SCORE 30
#define MAX_PROBLEM_2_SCORE 30
#define MAX_PROBLEM_3_SCORE 40

#define MAX_SCORE (MAX_PROBLEM_1_SCORE + MAX_PROBLEM_2_SCORE + MAX_PROBLEM_3_SCORE)

typedef struct student {
    size_t id;
    unsigned int prob_1;
    unsigned int prob_2;
    unsigned int prob_3;
    unsigned int total_score;
    char grade;
} student;

void cal_total_score(student* s, size_t length);
void student_bb_sort(student* s, size_t length);

int main() {
    student s[NUM_STUDENTS];
    unsigned int total_score;
    size_t i;

    const float lower_grade_threshold = ((float) MAX_SCORE) / 3;
    const float upper_grade_threshold = ((float) MAX_SCORE) * 2.0 / 3.0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; i++) {
        s[i].id = i;
        s[i].prob_1 = rand() % MAX_PROBLEM_1_SCORE + 1;
        s[i].prob_2 = rand() % MAX_PROBLEM_2_SCORE + 1;
        s[i].prob_3 = rand() % MAX_PROBLEM_3_SCORE + 1; 

        cal_total_score(&s[i], NUM_STUDENTS);
        
        printf("Student ID: %d\tP1: %d\tP2: %d\tP3: %d\tScore: %d\n",
               s[i].id, 
               s[i].prob_1, 
               s[i].prob_2, 
               s[i].prob_3, 
               s[i].total_score);
    }

    student_bb_sort(s, NUM_STUDENTS);
    printf("\nAfter Bubble Sort\n");

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; i++) {
        if (i < NUM_STUDENTS / 3) {
            s[i].grade = 'A';
        } else if (i < 2 * NUM_STUDENTS / 3) {
            s[i].grade = 'B';
        } else {
            s[i].grade = 'C';
        }

        printf("Student ID: %d\tScore: %d\tGrade: %c\n", 
                s[i].id, 
                s[i].total_score, 
                s[i].grade);
    }
}

void cal_total_score(student* s, size_t length) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        s[i].total_score = s[i].prob_1 + s[i].prob_2 + s[i].prob_3;
    }
}

void student_bb_sort(student* s, size_t length) {
    student tmp_student;
    int i, j;
    int swapped;

    do {
        swapped = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
            if (s[i - 1].total_score < s[i].total_score) {
                swapped = 1;
                tmp_student = s[i];
                s[i] = s[i - 1];
                s[i - 1] = tmp_student;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of advice. Thank you very much. It was very helpful. I think my skills have improved thanks to you.

Answer (score 3):

> But I wonder if there is a more efficient way.

Instead of *bubble-sort*, use `qsort()`.  Yet I expect OP's assignment may oblige *bubble-sort*.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int student_compar(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
  const Student *s1 = (const Student *) p1;
  const Student *s2 = (const Student *) p2;
  return (s1->total_score > s2->total_score) - (s1->total_score < s2->total_score);
}

...
// student_bb_sort(s);
qsort(s, NUMSTUDENT, sizeof s[0], student_cmp);
```

OP's code does not look like a proper [bubble_sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) as it lacks  the quick solution when the array is already sorted.  Perhaps as

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void student_bb_sort_alt(size_t n, Student* s) {
  bool sorted;
  do {
    sorted = true;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      if (s[i - 1].total_score > s[i].total_score) {
        Student tmp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[i - 1];
        s[i - 1] = tmp;
        sorted = false;
      }
    }
  } while (!sorted);
}
```

**Assign all the members, Fold loops together**

Calculate total score right after the `.prob_3` assignment.  A good practice it to avoid leaving members unassigned for long.  As the `.grade` is not know until much later, consider filling now with `U` for *unknown*.  This allows a common `student_display()` function to be called right away without unambiguous results, even before the sort.

```
    s[i].prob_3 = rand() % 40 + 1;

    // Add
    s[i].total_score = s[i].prob_1 + s[i].prob_2 + s[i].prob_3;
    s[i].grade = 'U';
```

**Avoid `float` for common FP math**

Use `double` for typical floating point (FP) math.  Use `float` in select cases when the size/(and sometimes speed) is important and not precision/range.

Definitely drop the `&& (float)i >= (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3`.  The test is redundant due to the prior `if()` and floating point math simple does things on edge cases that may cause this test to fail when you expect it to be true.

**Use integer math when able**

Use named thresholds. It self-documents code.

```
// for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
//     if ((float)i < (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3) {
//         s[i].grade = 'C';
//     }
//     else if ((float)i < (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3 * 2 && (float)i >= (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3) {
//         s[i].grade = 'B';
//     }
//     else {
//         s[i].grade = 'A';
//     }
//     printf("Student %d\tScore: %d\tGrade: %c\n", s[i].id, s[i].total_score, s[i].grade);
// }

int B_min = (NUMSTUDENT + 2)/ 3; // + 2 to function like (float)i < (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3.
int A_min = (NUMSTUDENT*2 + 2)/ 3;
for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
    if (i < B_min) {
        s[i].grade = 'C';
    }
    else if (i < A_min) {
        s[i].grade = 'B';
    }
    else {
        s[i].grade = 'A';
    }
    printf("Student %d\tScore: %d\tGrade: %c\n", s[i].id, s[i].total_score, s[i].grade);
}
```

**Advanced: Array indexing and sizing**

In select cases, `int` may be of insufficient range.  `size_t` is right sized for array indexing and object sizing. Note that `size_t` is some *unsigned* type.

```
//int i, j;
size_t i, j;

for (i = 1; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
```

**Bug!!**

OP's grading may result in 2 students with the same score getting different grades.

Imagine all sorted students in the 30% to 35% ordering had the same total.  Should not everyone get the same grade?

Instead of the first third getting a `C`. Use the 33% ordered student's score as a threshold.

```
int B_min = s[(NUMSTUDENT + 2)/ 3].total_score;
int A_min = s[(NUMSTUDENT*2 + 2)/ 3].total_score;
for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
    if (s[i].total_score < B_min) {
        s[i].grade = 'C';
    }
    else if (s[i].total_score < A_min) {
        s[i].grade = 'B';
    }
    else {
        s[i].grade = 'A';
    }
    printf("Student %d\tScore: %d\tGrade: %c\n", s[i].id, s[i].total_score, s[i].grade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think: Do not use bubble sort(BS), except it is your teacher's requirement. Because the time complexity for BS is n*n (n are the elements) if you want to sort

```
typedef struct student {
    int id;
    int prob_1;
    int prob_2;
    int prob_3;
    int total_score;
    char grade;
}Student;

// add comparator
bool operator<(const Student&  st1, const Student&  st2){
    return st1.total_score < st2.total_score; // please check whether it is  < or >
}
```

now if you have a `vector<Student> vec;` you can quickly sort it by built-in sort
The next thing is I do not know the benefit of using `size_t` except to save a little memory (If someone knows anything else please tell me).
But if you want to use size_t or unsigned int, you really should be careful with the problem: integer overflow, especially where the input from the users. For example:
Matrix(x,y); // when x and y are the input from users, and their data types are size_t or unsigned.
and if you expect that when the user's input is Matrix(-1, 2), it gives you an error or something so you are wrong, the program runs, and -1 will be the positive max number of `size_t`.

The last thing is: to try not to pass a pointer, instead use pass by reference.

Comment: `bool operator<()`, `vector<Student> vec` looks like a C++ suggestion for a C problem.  Perhaps provide a C suggestion instead?

Comment: Sorry I did see that we must use the C language, sorry I do not know whether lambda function can be used for C. If yes he can use the lambda function, please tell me so I can edit it.

Comment: Matching language answers are not a _must_.  Yet a learner of C (OP) might find a C++ confusing.  C does not have C++ like _lambda functions_.  Your call.

Answer (score 0):

Including some specification in `cal_total_score()` & `student_bb_sort()` is the way to go, credit going to the creators of the "problem" or a solution.

`read [the source code of main()] if you need it`

I need it to interpret `In each student, total_score must be the sum of prob_1, prob_2, and prob_3.`:
This function is called `NUMSTUDENT` times, with the address of each student in `s` in succession - looks like a better wording of the requirement was

```
// Problem (A): Implement the function "cal_total_score".
/** In Student s, set total_score to the sum of prob_1, prob_2, and prob_3. */
void cal_total_score(Student* s) {
    s->total_score = s->prob_1 + s->prob_2 + s->prob_3;
}
```

(The original requirement could as easily be fulfilled with
`s->prob_3 = s->total_score - s->prob_1 - s->prob_2;` -
`s->total_score = s->prob_1 = s->prob_2 = s->prob_3 = 0;` doesn't even need calculation.
)

Iterating `NUMSTUDENT` times in `cal_total_score()` does all the work useful in the first call.
Starting with `i`= 1, the call `cal_total_score(&s[i]);` (which I'd still code `cal_total_score(s + i);`)
results in access to `s[NUMSTUDENT]` - beyond the array, "undefined behaviour": anything may happen.

---

Implementing *bubble sort* is [reinventing the wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breinventing-the-wheel%5D+%22bubble+sort%22) - won't comment without the point of the exercise stated.
Most of what I think weird is in the code that seems to have been given (`typedef struct student Student;`?).

Comment: I put the comment stating what `cal_total_score()` is good for in a place and form where it can benefit [doxygen](https://doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).